# How to enable hardware support for H.264 encoding on raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, hardware-acceleration, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to enable the hardware support for H264 encoding on raspberry pi 4B model. Compiling FFmpeg source enabling the configurations

```
sudo ./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-nonfree
```

following the link, https://github.com/legotheboss/YouTube-files/wiki/(RPi)-Compile-FFmpeg-with-the-OpenMAX-H.264-GPU-acceleration

but while executing the encoding command after building and installing the ffmpeg with those configuration properly, I am getting the following error

```
[h264_omx @ 0x156b6e0] Using OMX.broadcom.video_encode
[h264_omx @ 0x156b6e0] OMX error 80001000
[h264_omx @ 0x156b6e0] err 80001018 (-2147479528) on line 561
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

command used:

```
ffmpeg -i /media/pi/pic_1_org.png -c:v h264_omx -c:a copy -b:v 1500k outputfile.mp4
```

I just want to encode a single 4K image into a .mp4 file using H.264 encoder. 
Please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hardware H.264 encoder on the Raspberry Pi 4 supports only resolutions of 1920x1080 or lower. So there is no hardware support for 4k encoding.

Comment: u correctly pointed out the fact. Can u plz also tell me how to get the exact time needed by H264_omx hardware encoder to encode a video?

Comment: I don’t think I understand your question

Comment: Then what is this about? `hevc_v4l2m2m` and `hevc_vaapi` - I get it vaapi wont work that's an Intel tech but the `hevc_v4l2m2m` looks like a hardware h265 encoder to me? Pi4

Comment: @PiotrKula - The question was about H.264/AVC not H.265/HEVC

Answer (score 1):

The version of ffmpeg available from apt now has hardware codecs so you can just install that using:

```
apt install ffmpeg
```

You can verify their presence like this:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep 'h264_omx\|h264_v4l2m2m'
```

There are two ways to use the hardware codec - either by using the newer `h264_v4l2m2m` or the `h264_omx` OMX based one.

Note: The `gpu_mem` setting in `/boot/config.txt` needs to be greater than 16 - otherwise you will get an error with both codecs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the ARMv6 NEON capability of raspberrypi4 with this simple command

```
ffmpeg -i 4k-input.mp4  -vf scale=-1:360  360p-output.mp4
```

don't add nothing!

Comment: can you please give a link with more information on this?