FPS reduction for H264
There is a USB camera that sends H264 frames with a frequency of 30 fps in a resolution of 1920x1080, GOP size 30 or 60 (1 or 2 I frame per second depending on the camera and only P-frames), which requires throughput of about 6 mbit/s. It is necessary to reduce this to no more than 2 mbit/s. All this is done on a weak ARMv7, so the option of transcoding is extremely resource intensive, especially considering that I did not find how to do it as a GPU Mali (NanoPi Neo Core).
# ./ffmpeg -hide_banner -codecs | grep h264
 DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_v4l2m2m )

# sudo ./ffmpeg -hide_banner -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -c:v h264_v4l2m2m -video_size 1920x1080 -threads 4 -i /dev/video0 -f null -
[h264 @ 0x149bb30] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 269427.784703, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x160fd40] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x160fd40] can't configure decoder
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_v4l2m2m) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Invalid argument


Given that the basic functionality is performed on the framework ffmpeg, is it possible to reduce the frame rate, ideally to 10 fps, WITHOUT loss of quality and decoding?
maybe I figured out how to define only I frames from NALU
#include "libavcodec/h264.h"
...
(AVPacket.data[4] & 0x1F) == H264_NAL_SPS

as I understood from what was written here, not every P-frame can depend on the previous one, which means I can not decode each slice and just skip the intermediate ones


Does your encoded video have B-frames? If yes, how many? You can [edit] your question to clarify.

Why is this tagged C++ and C?

because I use ffmpeg's libav C/C++ libraries in my project

There is no such language as C/C++.  It's either C or it's C++.

ok, gcc compiler version 6

No, you'd need to transcode.
You might be able to throw away the B frames and just keep the I and P frames but the resulting bitstream would be invalid and would depend on the decoder whether it would display properly. The B frames are also the smallest ones so removing them might not reduce the bitrate by much.
It looks like ffmpeg did support hardware encoding so that's likely to be the best option https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772902/5494370

Why would throwing away B-frames produce an invalid bitstream? Depending on that, it could be a fun exercise to make it valid.

Because there'd be pictures missing, they're numbered so the decoder might get confused, the I and P frames should normally be decodable without them but some decoders might object to the missing frames

@Alan Birtles The cameras do not contain B-frames and there are no such hardware codecs for NanoPi Neo Core

@АлександрА If you've only got p frames there's not much you can do, each frame depends on the previous one so you can only remove the ones at the end of each gop

@Alan Birtles Only a standard decoder use the CPU up to 28 fps and consumes 3/4 of the processor time, but I know that some analyze raw h264 frames to search for movement. Perhaps there is a mathematical way add up P-frames

@АлександрА you might be able to write such an algorithm but it's not a trivial task and I doubt it'd be significantly faster than just transcoding

@AlanBirtles as you can read, not every P-frame can depend on the previous one, so I can not decode each slice and just skip the intermediate ones.

@АлександрА yes there are some more complex gop structures that are used in some applications, do you have such a bitsream? Even if you do you'll still be limited to what frame rates you can reduce to

@Alan Birtles this is my question, which is unreasonably closed, how do I find out?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782447/gop-structure-via-ffmpeg

@Alan Birtles I know this, but it does not specify how to distinguish P frames from each other
